# A question on logic: Is this statement true or false

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is just messing with my head for the past hour.

Question:

$|(0,1)| = |(0,1]|$. If you find a bijection, you don't need to prove that its a bijection.

So a Bijection is one-on-one. E.g 
$f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ then $a_1=a_2$
and $\operatorname{range} f = B$

In the above case *It is bijective* is true but is the statement true as well?

and what about if its
$|[0,1]^2| = |[0,2]^2|$

Thanks
Edit:
Heres the exact wording of the question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MhxE.png

Comment: A bijection is more than one-to-one: it must also be onto.... You say "the statement is true, but is the statement true as well?" I don't understand what you are asking. If by $(0,1)^2$ and $(0,2)^2$ you mean the sets of all pairs of reals in the original interval, then, yes, $|(0,1)^2| = |(0,2)^2|$. The simplest way to see that is to show that $|(0,1)|=|(0,2)|$.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your question: do you perhaps mean to ask about whether $|(0,1)|=|(0,2)|$?

Comment: No for the first part it is |(0,1)|=|(0,1)|
And for 1 it is onto because onto means range f = B where B in that case would be {0,1} and range is also {0,1}

It is confusing I know! thats why I am asking here. Thats all the information thats provided, and it asks whether the statement is true or false. So for the first one I think the statement is true because in order for (0,1)| = |(0,1)| to be a function it has to be bijective.

Comment: Okay, that comment makes it even more confusing, because now we have $\{0,1\}$ thrown into the mix, as well.

Comment: When you write, "It is bijective", what doesn "It" refer to? Being bijective (or not) is a property of functions, and you haven't given one.

Comment: You transcribed your first correction incorrectly; it compares the intervals (0,1) (that is, the open unit interval) and (0,1] (that is, the semi-closed unit interval); the latter is the former plus the point {1}.  Notation is _essential_ to get right for examples like these, particularly if you want us to be able to help you.

Comment: You also copied the second question incorrectly. I've edited the question to fix these errors.

Comment: BTW the first part of the question was also poster [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-do-i-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1).

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: In response to your posting of the exact wording of the problem, here is a refined version of my answer.

In the first case, you are trying to show that $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $(0,1]$. A bijection $(0,1]\to(0,1)$ that works is $$h(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n+1} & x=\frac{1}{n},\,n\in\Bbb N\\x & \mathrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ It is a good exercise to show this is a bijection (even though you don't have to for the assignment).

In the second case, you are trying to show that $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has the same cardinality as $[0,2]\times[0,2]$. As Arturo points out, the way to start, here, is by finding a bijection $[0,1]\to[0,2]$ (which shouldn't be too difficult). Say that $f$ is such a bijection. Then if we define $g:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to[0,2]\times[0,2]$ by $g(x,y)=\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle$, we have the desired bijection.

Comment: Notational tip: if you have open intervals, use $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ for ordered pairs.

Comment: Excellent point. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, an answer to your first question (edited), "Is $|(0,1)| = |(0, 1]|$?" can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-do-i-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1).

For your second question (also edited), "Is $|[0,1]^2| = |[0, 2]^2|$?", the answer is also "yes": The function $f(x) = 2x$ is obviously a bijection from $[0, 1]\text{ and }[0,2]$ and it's easy to extend this to the product by defining $g:[0,1]^2\rightarrow [0,2]^2$ to be $g((x,y)) = (2x, 2y).$

Comment: I believe that the OP knows about the answer to the first question, as the OP also posted the question you linked to.

Comment: @Cameron Heh. I missed that. Thanks.