# Find a one-to-one correspondence between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-do-i-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1)

Establish a one-to-one correspondence between the closed interval $[0,1]$ and the open interval $(0,1)$.

this is a problem in real analysis.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: taking the domain to be $[0,1]$, define the images of $0$, $1$, $1/2$, $1/3$, $\ldots$ first.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160738/5363).

Answer (score 7):

Possibly you are considering this problem in [this textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880157020) but probably not; in any case, the author suggest breaking the proof down into two lemmas that may help you prove this problem:

Part (a): Suppose there are sets $ A,B  $ which have a subset $S$ in common and that for some sets $C,D$ we have

- $A = C \cup S \text{ and } B = D \cup S$
- $C \cap S = \emptyset \text{ and } D \cap S = \emptyset$
- there is a 1-1 correspondence between $C,D $

Then use this information to describe a 1-1 correspondence between $A,B$.

Part (b): Describe a 1-1 correspondence between the sets
$$\left\{0,1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots \right\} \text{ and } \left\{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4} \dots  \right\}  $$

Use Parts (a),(b) to prove that the intervals $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ are equivalent sets.

Comment: I really appreciate the restraint here, especially from a new user. Good answer, +1

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the construction used in the [Wikipedia proof of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) yields an elegant answer.

Take, for instance, $A = [-1,1]$ and $B = (-1,1)$. For the injective map $g:B\rightarrow A$ we can just take the identity, and for $f:A \rightarrow B$ we can use $f(x) = x/2$.

Following through with the construction yields a bijection $\psi: A \rightarrow B$ which is the identity almost everywhere except at points of the form $\pm2^{-n}$.