# Function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ taking on each value in $[0,1]$ exactly twice

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find a function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $f$ takes on each value in $[0,1]$ exactly twice. I think this means there are an infinite number of discontinuities. Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: That is actually a pretty cool problem.

Comment: See Jo Heath, "Every exactly 2-to-1 function on the reals has an infinite
number of discontinuities", Proceedings of the AMS, 98 (1986), 369-373 http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-098-02/S0002-9939-1986-0854049-8/S0002-9939-1986-0854049-8.pdf

Comment: Wouldn't a rather natural solution be to split the unit interval into a closed and a half-open interval and to construct bijections for each?

Comment: @wj32 I am not sure exactly what function that could be though

Comment: @JacksonHart: It's difficult to describe the function explicitly, because we are relying on the fact that there is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(1/2,1]$. See this related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-do-i-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1

Comment: Does anyone know how to explicitly define such a function?

Comment: Let $[0,1]$ be partitioned into the set of reciprocals of integers $A=1,1/2,1/3,...$ and the complement $B$ of $A$. Now map $A$ by a shift of the sequence (take 1 to 1/2, take 1/2 to 1/3, etc), and map $B$ by the identity. Then this will map $[0,1]$ bijectively to $[0,1)$.

Comment: @coffeemath: Nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_\alpha$ be a well-ordering of $[0,1]$.

For any ordinal $\alpha = \theta + n < \frak{c}$ where $\theta$ is a limit ordinal or $0$ and $n$ is a finite ordinal, let $F(\theta + n \cdot 2) = F(\theta + n \cdot 2 + 1) = x_\alpha$.

Now define $f(x_\alpha) = F(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \lt \frak{c}$ and it is clear that $f$ has the required property.

Comment: This is a overblown considering @EuYu's comment.  I do need practice with this kind of proof but it's not appropriate for this problem.