# Can a continuous real function take each value exactly 3 times?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is there a function $f$ that satisfies the following property? $\forall y \in D$, there are exactly 3 $ x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3) = y$.

Comment: How about $f:\Bbb R \to \{0\}$ defined by $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: Oops, I meant there are exactly 3 points $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525694/show-that-a-continuous-function-on-infty-infty-cannot-take-every-real-v.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla , I tried a similar approach. Consider the intervals $[x_1,x_2],[x_2,x_3]$. Then we have a maximum in each interval, $M_1,M_2$. Let $M = max\{M_1,M_2\}$. I can show that $M$ must appear at least twice in $(-\infty,x_1) \cup (x_1,\infty)$, but I can't figure out any kind of contradiction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer is yes. Consider the piece-wise affine function described in this (poor) chart: [image]

Comment: PS: was too lazy to give a parametrization but I'd still be curious to see one

Answer (score 6):

There are many examples, e.g

- as a piecewise cubic curve
  $$x + 16\{x\}^3 - 24\{x\}^2 + 8\{x\}
  = x + \frac12\bigg[T_{n}(2\{x\}-1)-(2\{x\}-1)\bigg]
  $$
  where $T_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ [Chebyshev polynomials of first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind). Please note that if one replace $n$ by other odd positive integers, we will obtain a function whose pre-images come in group of $n$ instead of group of $3$.

[image: A piecewise cubic curve]

- or even as a smooth curve
  $$(\cos\theta) x - \sin x \quad\text{ with }\quad \cos\theta \sim 0.21723362821122$$
  and $\theta$ is a root of $\;\tan\theta = \pi + \theta\;$ near $1.35$.

[image: A smooth curve]

Answer (score 5):

Let $\phi\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $\phi(x)=1-3\,|x-1/3|$ and let
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(\phi(x-k)-k)\,\chi_{[k,k+1]}(x).
$$
where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$.
[image]

Comment: this is interesting. Does this approach generalize for $n\geq 3$ if we define $\phi(x,n) = 1 - n|x - \frac{1}{n}|$?

Comment: @user194082: intuitively, for every even $n$ there will be no such $f$ (not checked, but likely to be similar to case $n=2$)

Comment: The $3$ is just for convenience. It has nothing to do with the fact that $f(x)=y$ has exactly $3$ solutions.

Answer (score 1):

With $D=\mathbb R$, let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x-3\lfloor x\rfloor &\text{if $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is even}\\3-4x+3\lfloor x\rfloor&\text{if $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is odd}\end{cases}$$