# Find a continuous function over reals that takes on every value exactly three times

Tags: calculus

> Find a continuous function over reals that takes on every value exactly three times.

I was thinking such a function would have to have two critical points and must go from increasing to decreasing or decreasing to increasing. Something like $x^3$, but still there are some points there that aren't counted three times. How would I go about constructing such a function?

Comment: There exist $a,b$ such that $f(x)=ax+b\sin x$ works.

Comment: There is an old answer on MSE that gives a piecewise linear solution, but I can't find it now

Comment: see answers of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/735842/59379), [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1030585/59379) and the questions linked to them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The picture should suffice, but SE requires some characters.

Comment: What about its equation?

Comment: You'll find a formula at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735842/function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-takes-each-value-in-mathbbr-th (from the comment above). If I'd seen that comment I wouldn't have posted my duplicate answer.