# Function taking on all values thrice

Tags: continuity, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

I recently saw the following puzzle somewhere:

> Find a continuous, surjective function $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$ that takes on each of its values exactly three times.

Or, more technically stated,

> Find a continuous, surjective function $f:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R$, such that for all $y\in\mathbb R$, there exist exactly three real solutions $x$ to the equation $f(x)=y$.

My solution to this puzzle was the function
$$f(x)=\sin^2 \frac{3\pi(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}{2}+\lfloor x\rfloor$$
Since then, I've thought of a few variations on this puzzle, none of which I have been able to solve:

> - Can a function $g:\mathbb R\mapsto \mathbb R^2$ satisfy these requirements? What about a function $h:\mathbb R^2\mapsto \mathbb R$?
> - What function $f$ satisfies the original puzzle, and is also $C^\infty$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030585/can-a-continuous-real-function-take-each-value-exactly-3-times which is itself a duplicate.

Comment: @Nilknarf: It would be a good idea to highlight your actual questions.

Comment: There's a smooth example in [achille hui's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1030738/1242) to the linked question.

Comment: I didn't say this question is a duplicate. I said that *that* question was a duplicate, so people would know to trace back to see whether there's anything at either question of interest here.

Comment: Regarding your first question, there is no such $h$, because if $h(x)\neq h(y)$ then by the intermediate value theorem every value between $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ is attained along every path from $x$ to $y$.  I.e. every intermediate value is attained infinitely many times.

Comment: I am convinced that there is no such $g$ either, but it appears considerably more difficult to prove.  See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43096/is-it-true-that-a-space-filling-curve-cannot-be-injective-everywhere

They succeed in proving that no injective $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ exists, but the proof doesn't seem to extend to the present case.

Comment: @gimusi What about the second question? Did you solve that one?

Comment: @Nilknarf Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting from the following idea:

$$g(x)=\sin x + \frac{2}{3\pi}x$$

[g(x) plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciibg.jpg)

we can adjust the constant for x in such way that

$$f(x)=\sin x + Kx$$

fullfills the given condition.

The value of K can be easily found imposing that:

$$\begin{cases}(\sin x)'=\cos x=-K\\
Kx=-\sin x\end{cases}$$

$$\implies tanx=x \implies x\approx4.49340945790906 \quad K=-\cos x \approx 0.21723362821123...$$

[f(x) plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%2B0.21723362821122573300830319268567855144747547081697341459x)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. This function has 4 zeroes.

Comment: @Nilknarf: the idea is correct, however. If $\frac{2}{3\pi}$ is replaced by the solution of a trascendental equation, $\sin(x)+K x$ is an entire function attaining each real value exactly three times.

Comment: @Nilknarf why 4 zeros? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sinx%2B(2%2F(3pi))x,+x%3D-20..20

Comment: @gimusi: the correct constant is not $\frac{2}{3\pi}$ but $0.21723362821122\ldots$. The graphs of $\sin(x)$ and $-\frac{2}{3\pi}x$ are not tangent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, it's clear to me now!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio later I'll try to find the equation for this value!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it should be the $K$ from the simultaneous solution of $\sin x+Kx=0$ and $\cos x+K=0$ on $x$ and $K$ with the smallest possible positive value for $x$. Alternatively, the largest $K$ so that both equations have a simultaneous solution.

Comment: Very nice, gimusi. My apologies if you disliked my edits, I was not sure you would come back and finish this your own way, as you now have. In case of interest: I suspect a similar type of thing, just different $K,$ might give each value exactly five times.

Comment: @WillJagy I don't dislike but I prefer to complete myself my own answer, you can add another answer with any futher information and graph. Thanks!

Comment: I added the graph(s) for five times.

Comment: @WillJagy well done!

Answer (score 2):

I like Jack's description, draw a fixed sine curve and find tangent lines through the origin. In this case, I am finding a tangent point with $2 \pi < x < \frac{5 \pi}{2}.$ Under the circumstances, the slope $K$ comes out positive, with $K \approx 0.128374554, $ solution of $$K \left( 2 \pi + \arccos K \right) = \sqrt {1 - K^2}$$
The $x$ value for the tangent is about $7.725251838,$ just below $\frac{5 \pi}{2} \approx 7.853981635$$

[image]

This time, we get each value assumed by the function **five** times, the function being $\sin x - K x.$

[image]

Alright, I widened out to include $\pm 14,$ and clicked so it shows the roots and critical points. It says there are critical points at $x \approx \pm 14.008$

[image]