# Prove $[ (-1)^{⌊x⌋+⌊\frac{x}{n}⌋}~\cdot~(x-⌊x⌋-\frac{1}{2}) ]+ ⌊\frac{x}{n}⌋ + \frac{1}{2}$ is continuous if $n$ is odd.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

This comes from problem 21c of Chapter 7 of Spivak's Calculus 4th Edition.

21c) Find a continuous function $f$ which takes on every value exactly $n$ times, where $n$ is odd.

The solution I came up is $f_n(x)= [ (-1)^{⌊x⌋+⌊\frac{x}{n}⌋}~\cdot~(x-⌊x⌋-\frac{1}{2}) ]+ ⌊\frac{x}{n}⌋ + \frac{1}{2}$

Where $⌊x⌋$ is the floor function.

It seems to work, but I want to prove it works. Well atleast I want to prove it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. No idea where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735842/function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-takes-each-value-in-mathbbr-th/895427#895427) with a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continuity of $f_n$**

For $x \in [kn + i, kn+i + 1)$ with $(n,i) \in \mathbb Z \times \{0, \dots, n-1\}$ you have $\lfloor x \rfloor = kn+i$, $\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor = k$ and

$$\begin{aligned}f_n(x) &= \left[(-1)^{k(n+1)+i}\left(x-kn-i -\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] + k + \frac{1}{2}\\
&= \left[(-1)^{i}\left(x-kn-i -\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] + k + \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}$$ and therefore for $x \in [kn + i, kn+i + 1)$

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
x-kn-i+k &\text{ for } i \text{ even}\\
-x+kn+i+k+1  &\text{ for } i \text{ odd}
\end{cases}$$

Based on that we get for $i$ even

$$\lim\limits_{x \to (kn+i+1)^-} f_n(x)= k+1 = f_n(kn+i+1)$$ and for $i$ odd

$$\lim\limits_{x \to (kn+i+1)^-} f_n(x)= k= f_n(kn+i+1).$$

Knowing that $f_n$ is continuous on all intervals $(kn + i, kn+i + 1)$, this allows to conclude that $f_n$ is continuous on each interval $(kn, k(n+1))$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$. As

$$\lim\limits_{x \to kn^-} f_n(x)=k= f_n(kn)$$ we can finally conclude that $f_n$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

**Values taken by $f_n$**

1. $g_n(x)=f_n(x) - ⌊\frac{x}{n}⌋$ is a periodic map with $n$ as a period.
2. $g_n$ takes exactly $n$ times each value of $(0,1)$ on the interval $(0,n)$.
3. The cardinal of $f^{-1}_n(\{0\})$ is equal to $n$.
4. For all $x \in \mathbb R$ $f_n(x+n) = f_n(x)+1$.
5. Conclude.

*This can also be seen directly from the study of the continuity and the values taken on each interval on which $f_n$ is linear.*

Comment: What does cardinal, and $f^{-1}_n(\{0\})$ mean?

Comment: The number of elements $x$ such that $f_n(x)=0$.

Comment: I don't understand... This chain of reasoning would prove $f$ takes every value $n$ times, but how would it prove $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @SenZen Continuity added in the answer.