# Give an example of a continuous function $f:R\rightarrow R$ which attains each of its values exactly three times.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

- Give an example of a continuous function $f:R\rightarrow R$ which attains each of its values exactly three times.

*Ed.: answered by the duplicate above*

- Does there exist a continuous function $f:R\rightarrow R$ which attains each of its values exactly two times?

*Ed.: answered by* [$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that takes each value in $\mathbb{R}$ twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730692/147263)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730692/f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-takes-each-value-in-mathbbr-twice/730712#730712

Comment: I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735842/function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-that-takes-each-value-in-mathbbr-th?rq=1

Comment: think about a $\sin x$ function on an appropriate interval

Comment: thank you all for helping me.

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate, because the other question do not ask to exhibit a function with the property that any value in the image is took three times.

Comment: Neither it is a duplicate of the other question, it is just both of them. It would have some sense to merge the three questions into this topic.

Comment: I don't know about merging; another reason it is not a duplicate of the other "three times" question is because that one did not ask for continuity.  Although this question did get answered there, I don't know that that is enough to make the more difficult question a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x)=2\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3\pi}\right\rfloor-\cos\left(3\pi\left\{\frac{x}{3\pi}\right\}\right)\tag{1}$$
is a differentiable function that attains any real value in exaclty three points, whose graphics is the following one:

$\hskip2in$[image]

If in $(1)$ you replace "$3$" with the positive odd integer $2m+1$, you get a $C^1$-function that attains any real value in exactly $2m+1$ points. You can also take:

$$f(x) = T_{2m+1}\left(x-2\left\lceil\frac{x-1}{2}\right\rceil\right)+2\left\lceil\frac{x-1}{2}\right\rceil,$$

where $T_{2m+1}$ is the $(2m+1)$-th [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html). This is a $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ function, too.

---

You cannot have a continuous function $g$ that takes any value in $g(\mathbb{R})$ exactly twice. Such function cannot be monotonic, hence must have a point $x_0$ of local maximum/minimum and another point $x_1\neq x_0$ for which $g(x_1)=g(x_0)$. Then, by continuity, there exists a constant $G$ sufficiently close to $g(x_0)$ but different from $g(x_0)$ such that there are two points $y_1,y_2$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (because $x_0$ is a maximum/minimum), and at least one point $y_3$ in a neighbourhood of $x_1$ such that 
$$ g(y_1)=g(y_2)=g(y_3)=G,$$
contradiction.

Comment: Very nice example :-)

Comment: Are you sure you want those curly brackets in the argument of the cosine?

Comment: @MiguelAngelAlarconBustos: I am pretty sure. Why do they bother you?

Comment: Well, because it would be just $\cos(x)$ so they don't play a very important role there (unless they mean something different from what I am  thinking). And I was trying to plot it on matplotlib and it wasn't continuous