# Cardinality of any bounded interval of ℝ = |ℝ|?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A bit of background on why I'm asking this:

Take the sequence of ℤ+, which has the same cardinality as ℤ:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

Suppose we create a number in base 11 using `x` as the extra symbol, by concatenating the numbers, and delimiting with `x`.

```
1x2x3x4x5x6x...
```

This is a perfectly legal number in our base 11 scheme.

Now scale it:

```
0.1x2x3x4x5x6x...
```

This would be a real number between 0 and 1 [0, 1).

In other words, this real number represents the sequence ℤ+ and consists of a single point *p* on the real number line, 0 ≤ *p* < 1.

Take any other sequence in ℤ+, transform it the same way, and it can be represented as a point *p* on the real number line, 0 ≤ *p* < 1:

```
0.10x20x30x40x... times ten
0.1x4x9x16x25x... squares
0.41x8x20x9x5x... some random sequence
```

All finite sequences of similar length can also be represented similarly. For example, all finite sequences of length 2: `{1, 1} {1, 2} {1, 3} ...` can be ordered and represented by a single number in ℝ:

```
0.1x1x1x2x1x3x...
```

So we have the set of all sequences, finite and infinite, representable as a point *p*, 0 ≤ *p* < 1.

These sequences can be scaled to any arbitrary [*q*, *r*) such that *r* → *q*, but always *r* > *q*.

Given that [*q*, *r*) is an arbitrarily small but bounded interval in ℝ, and that ℤ+ is represented as a single point *p'*, *q* ≤ *p'* < *r*, can it be argued that the size of this set is larger than ℤ but smaller that ℝ?

I guess it all hinges on whether the cardinality of any bounded interval of ℝ = |ℝ|, hence the title of the question.

Comment: Consider the function $\tan x$, which maps from a finite range to the entire set of real numbers.  Note that $\tan x$ over its finite domain is one to one and onto and thus proves the cardinalities are equal.

Comment: The interval $[q,r)$ is neither infinitely small nor finite, for any $r > q$.  The intersection or "limit set" of all these sets is just the single point $q$, but you can't map all the integer sequences to it.  This is basically another example of behavior of a sequence not matching the behavior of the limit.

Comment: @abiessu, thank you for such a clear and concise answer.

Comment: Generally, the question has been asked ad nauseum on this site. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200180/is-there-a-bijective-map-from-0-1-to-mathbbr is a particular example, and there are more - much more - examples for closed, open, left-closed and right-open, and right-closed and left-open, and so on.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila - If the question is asked ad nauseum then that might be an indication that the matching done by SO isn't working so well. It was only when I revised the title to use "bounded interval" did proper matches show up.

Comment: @Russell: Bounded interval is the standard terminology. Finite interval is **not** a standard terminology. This is not the software's fault that it cannot guess your terminology.

Comment: [Show that open segment $(a,b)$, close segment $[a,b]$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300815/show-that-open-segment-a-b-close-segment-a-b-have-the-same-cardinality/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\tan x$ (among others, but tangent is easy to use) can be mapped from any specific range in the real numbers to the entire set of reals.  In particular, let the range $[a,b]$ be given where $a\ne b$, then $\forall x\in (a,b),$
$$ f(x)=\tan\left({\pi\cdot (x-a)\over b-a}-{\pi\over 2}\right)$$
 supplies this mapping.

Since it is possible to pick any real number $r$ and find $x_r$ such that $f(x_r)=r$, and vice versa, this function is one to one and onto, and is thus a complete mapping AKA bijection from a bounded interval of the reals to the entire set, which means that the cardinalities are the same.

Comment: Yes, but you and the OP should not be saying "finite range" when you mean "bounded interval". Also when you say "complete mapping" you mean "1-1 and onto mapping" or "bijection". Apologies for being pedantic.

Comment: No apologies necessary, I have forgotten much of what it means to be exact and I am relearning by attempting to answer questions like this, and by getting constructive criticism such as you have provided.