# To prove that $(a,b)$ is equivalent to $(c,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are said to be equivalent, if there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

To prove that $(a,b)$ is equivalent to $(c,d)$

Now I need a map which maps $a$ to $c$ and $b$ to $d$ and all numbers in between. I am thinking that decimal representation of number swill play some role here, like $a.a_1a_2a_3...$ is being mapped to $c.a_1a_2a_3...$ but I am not able to find explicitly such function.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use a linear function with $a\mapsto c$ and $b\mapsto d$

Comment: Note that the mapping $x\to \alpha x$ scales the interval $[a,b]$ by a factor of $\alpha$. Moreover, $x\to x+\beta$ sends the interval on an interval of the same length $\beta$ units further. So it's possible to find a mapping $x\to \alpha x +\beta$ such that $[a,b]$ is sent on $[c,d]$

Comment: This may be my own preference and 'equivalent' may be the terminology your text, professor or course is using but I like to be very clear in my language in which case I would opt for saying "two sets have the same cardinality or are equinumerous/equipotent/equipollent if there exists a bijection between them". Many branches of math study different equivalence relations between sets determined by the existence of some type of morphism between them so I try to always be clear what exactly the "equivalent" relation I am interested in is.

Comment: Try with this: draw in the cartesian plane the two points of coordinates $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$. Now with a ruler draw the segment connecting these two points. You have just drawn the graph of your bijection!

Comment: @Janik Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @H.Potter But without knowing anything about intervals how can we find a mapping or we have to make different cases

Comment: @Crostul How on earth is this?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Comment: @Crostul If i apply Lagrange interpolation with these two points i get interpolating polynomial. But i need function

Comment: Isn't the interpolating polynomial a function?

Comment: @Crostul Thanks for help. i got it now. btw why downvotes?

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvotes. But it wasn't me.

Answer (score 1):

If $d-c = b-a$ then instantly there's a bijection: just translate one set onto the other.

Otherwise, translate both sets so $a=c=0$.
Then multiply everything in the "smaller" set by something appropriate to make sure the two sets' least upper bounds are equal.

---

Alternative method: we instead show that every bounded open interval bijects with $\mathbb{R}$. This is covered by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/490068/259262 .

Comment: How to  translate both sets so $a=c=0$

Comment: To "translate" is to add a constant.