# Difference between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Are the set of real number within the interval $[0,1]$ and the set of real number within the interval $[0,1)$ both countable?

I meet 2 questions respectively ask about the countability of the set of real number within the interval $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$? I thought there aren't really have great difference, and are both uncountable. But I am not sure if I'm right. Do anyone has any idea? Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking about a bijection between the two sets?

Comment: $[0,1) \cup \{1\} = [0,1]$

Comment: with $[0,1)\cap\{1\}=\emptyset.$

Comment: They are indeed very close relatives, and in particular hsve the same cardinality. However, *verifying* that they do using bijections is a nice exercise in technique.

Comment: Although [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-do-i-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1) is about $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$, the answers can easily be adapted to produce a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is countable, then whenever $X=A\cup\{a\}$, we have that $X$ is countable, and vice versa. If $A$ is countable then $A\setminus\{a\}$ is countable, for any $a\in A$.

Since $[0,1]=[0,1)\cup\{1\}$ either both $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$ are countable, or both are uncountable. But going further from that, you can actually find a bijection between the two sets, which says *more* than their uncountability, but rather that they have the same cardinality.

To show that both are uncountable you need to prove there is no surjection from $\Bbb N$ onto $[0,1]$. Another way would be to prove that there is an injection from a set that you already know is uncountable (e.g. $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ or $\Bbb R$) into $[0,1)$.