# Bijection between $\mathbb N^+ \times \mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^+$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb N^+$ denote the set of natural numbers bigger than $0$ and let $\mathbb R^+$ denote the set of real numbers bigger than $0$.

Is there a way to write down an explicit bijection between $\mathbb N^+ \times \mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R^+$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace $\mathbb{N}^+$ by $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0 , 1 , 2 ... \}$. Also $\psi : \mathbb{R}^+ \cong [0,1)$.
Then the required bijection can be
$$ \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \ni  (n,r) \longmapsto n+\psi(r) \in \mathbb{R}^+ \ .$$

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the map.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

Consider $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x}$, it is a bijection $\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb [0,1[$. Now, $g(n,x)=n+x$ is a bijection like you want.

Comment: This is actually a bijection $\mathbb{R}^+ \to (0,1)$, not $[0,1)$, since according to the OP's notation $0 \not \in \mathbb{R}^+$. What you get is *almost* a bijection, but there are countably many points not in the image of the function.

Comment: it depends if "bigger" in the question means strictly bigger or $\geq$. Anyway it is not hard to go from one to the other with bijections.

Comment: No element of $\mathbb N$ is in the range of that function...

Comment: Finding a bijection $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{R}$ is pretty hard if you want a neat explicit description. (FWIW, "bigger than" unambiguously means $>$ and not $\ge$.)

Comment: You just need bijections $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N^+$ and $\mathbb R^+\cup\{0\}\to \mathbb R^+$ (and the first gives the second by the way).

Answer (score 3):

Well, there exist the following bijections:

1. An explicit bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$ (namely, scaled the co-tan function)
2. An explicit bijection between $\mathbb R^+$ and $\mathbb R$ (the $\exp$ function)
3. An explicit bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$

This means there exists an explicit bijection between $\mathbb R^+$ and any semiclosed interval of $(a,a+1]$ length $1$, call that $f_{a}$. Now just create a bijection from $\mathbb N^+\times \mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R^+$ from the individual $f_a$s

Answer (score 1):

There are many bijections between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$. Using them you can get easily bijection between $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Z = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z} (z,z+1)$.

So it only remains to modify the bijection to include integers. This can be done using "Hilbert hotel type" argument. (Something similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-do-i-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1), with the difference that now you want to add infinitely many elements.)

**EDIT:** I have worked with $\mathbb R$ and not $\mathbb R^+$. As other answers explain, there is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^+$. So this problem can be solved, too.

Comment: Might as well use $(0,1]$ so you can get all of $\mathbb R$... I guess that's just using Hilbert's hotel one step earlier...