# Build a bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Build a bijection $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}$.

What about $f(x)=\pi \cdot x?$

Comment: Fails for $x=\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: See also: [Find a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R-\mathbb N$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068949/find-a-bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-mathbb-n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map $\mathbb{Z}$ bijectively to $\{...,-3,-2,-1,0\}$ and leave the other points from $\mathbb{R}$ untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: do you know how to build a bijection $[0,1]\to (0,1]$? You "hide" $0$ somewhere inside an interval (in some infinite sequence). In your case you can hide all positive integers in some sequence too.

Update: you can choose any sequence $\{a_i\}$ and for all $n\in\mathbb{N} \quad f(n) = a_{2n},$ for elements from sequence $f(a_i) = a_{2i+1},$ and otherwise $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Shouldn't a bijection cover the entire range of $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{N}$ in the other direction?

Comment: @barakmanos, excuse me, I do not completely understand your remark. I've updated my post, though.