# Bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$

Tags: functions

Could one give me a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$ ?

I am trying to find a function $f:[0,2]\to[0,2]$ such that $\forall0\le x\le2,f^{-1}(x)$ is a tuple (2 elements), and such a bijection would give me an answer easily.

Comment: A very small modification in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/160741/12042) or [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/160750/12042) to a very similar question will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

How about sending
$$\frac1n\mapsto\frac1{n+1}$$
where $n\ge 1$ is an integer. Leave the rest unchanged.