# Do there exists continuous functions on compact sets with infinite length?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it possible to construct a continuous function from $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ whose length is infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Try $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\sin(1/x)$. This curve has unbounded variation, so in particular it is not rectifiable.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Because *1.* is a discrete function, the below does not actually describe a continuous function.**

Yes. Note that:

1. [A bijection exists between $[0, 1]$ and $(0, 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1)

Then:

2. A bijection exists between $(0, 1)$ and $ℝ$   —   $f(x) = \ln(\frac{1}{x}-1)$

Or, to use a more classic example:

2. A bijection exists between $(0, 1)$ and $(-π,π)$   —   $f(x) = 2πx-π$
3. A bijection exists between $(-π,π)$ and $ℝ$   —   $f(x) = \tan(x)$

∴  A bijection exists between $[0,1]$ and $ℝ$

Comment: This isn't continuous.

Comment: Oh, of course, my bad. I'll leave the answer here though for the sake of anyone coming here from Google who might be looking for this. Unless anyone has any objections or knows of a better question to move this answer to.