# Explicit bijection between $[0,1)$ and $(0,1)$

Tags: functions, cardinals

Proving that $[0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ have the same cardinality (without assuming any previous knowledge) can be done easily using Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

However I'm wondering if someone can build an explicit bijection between these sets.

It's easy to build a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$, so a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ will also fit the bill.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1?rq=1) question.

Comment: @Krijn, that's exactly what I need. Too bad it didn't come up in the suggestions when I wrote my question. Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: It comes up on the right of this page under Related, third entry.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it should also appear here: http://imgur.com/5L9qViH

Comment: I agree that it should have appeared there. Luckily, from now on, it wil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us partition $(0,1)$ into a countable number of disjoint subsets of the form $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.

These half-open intervals may then be positioned in reverse order to form a half-open interval of equal length.  Whether this construction is sufficiently explicit is open to question, but it does allow the relocation of any $x\in (0,1)$ to $[0,1)$ to be computed in short order.

A more succinct construction is to define $f:[0,1) \to (0,1)$ by $f(0) = 1/2$, $f(1/n) = 1/(n+1)$ for integer $n \ge 2$, and $f(x) = x$ otherwise.

Comment: Interesting idea. I wonder where I saw it already. Hey, wait a minute...

Comment: @Did: I'm sure you will believe that I answered without look at your previous Answer, but I've converted my post to CW out of deference to your note.