# Bijective function need not implies continious

Tags: real-analysis

Is   there exist  a bijective function from $[0, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I think  it will not possible  because $[0, 1)$ is not  isomorphic $\mathbb{R}$

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Why don't you think it will be possible? Also $[0,1)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ in what sense?

Comment: @jgon I believe she means the function cannot be a homeomorphism because it cannot be continuous.

Comment: @Sobi Where does $\frac{1}{2}$ go?

Comment: @JohnDuoma Ouch, good point! I have removed the comment.

Comment: @JohnDouma..can u  tell me  the particular  function ??

Comment: @jasmine I can't off the top of my head. One has to exist because we know that this interval and $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: @JohnDouma I thought that was likely as well, nonetheless my first question was really the more important one. The question is missing context, which is why I posted a comment asking for more information.

Comment: @jasmine This may be what you need. https://people.math.osu.edu/husen.1/teaching/345/equinumerous_intervals.pdf

Comment: @JohnDouma  as$ [0,1)$  now   removed 0 from $[0,1)$ that will (0,1)   which  is  connected     but $ \mathbb{R}  -\{0\}$..not connected   as continious image of connected set is   connected..here  f will not contnious

Comment: @JohnDouma....i will read      wait for  5 minutes

Comment: @jasmine I am aware of that but a bijection does not have to be continuous.

Comment: Well, we learned on the streets that the cardinality of $[0,1)$ is $\aleph_1$ and the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is $\aleph_1$ and we learned in an adult-supervised classroom that the *definition* of equal cardinality is that a bijection exists.  So even if we don't know *why* we know the answer to whether a bijection exists is .. yes.  A bijection *must* exist because they have the same cardinality.  ... That's the answer... now lets try to make *sense* of it.

Comment: @fleablood thanks  and  Good  logics

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425492/explicit-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1 this might help!

Comment: ..And we know we can stretch $0 \to -\infty$ and $1\to \infty$ by... doing something with $\frac 1{something}$ or $\arctan$s or something.  So we can probably have $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$ if we think about it.  But we have an extra point $0$.  Where do we put it? Well, we put it to $x_1$ so were do we put $f^{-1}(x_1)$.  Well, we put it to $x_2$.  Well, where do we put $f^{-1}(x_2)$.  Well we put it to $x_3$ and so on.  The question is: *can* we do that?  We know the answer is yes.  So take a bunch of scratch paper and ... see what you can noodle out.

Comment: ..In particular take $0\to f(\frac 12)$ then $\frac 12 \to f(\frac 12)$ then ... $\frac 1{2^k} \to f(\frac 1{2^{k+1}})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the identity on $[0,1)$. Then send $0$ to $1/2,$ $1/2$ to $1/3,$ etc. In the end you get a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$. To get a bijection, in fact, a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$, you can use eg. $\tan(\pi x - \pi /2)$.

You cannot get a continuous bijection of $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$ though because then the image of $(0,1)$ has to be an interval. But you get $\mathbb R \setminus\{\text{image of 0}\}.$

Answer (score 1):

How to get intuition to an answer.

We figure we can find a bijection $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R = (-\infty, \infty)$ by stretching $0\to -\infty$ and $1 \to\infty$.  We aren't sure of the details but we figure we can work those out.

But $[0,1)$ has that $0$ at the endpoint and whatever $f(0)$ maps to then $[0, \epsilon)$ will map to a clopen interval $(f(\epsilon), f(0)]$ or $[f(0),f(\epsilon))$ but we won't be able to continuously map to points immediately to the other side of $f(0)$ and this is because $[0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

But then we realize the bijection doesn't need to be continuous.  And as $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ are infinite and $0$ is just *one* extra point they have a the same cardinality which, by definition, means a bijection must exist.

We can use $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ (once we figure out the details) and then the issue if finding $g:[0,1) \to (0,1)$ that is bijective so $f\circ g:[0,1) \to (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ will be bijective.

We have to map $0\to x_1\ne 0$.  That means we must map $x_1\to x_2\ne x_1$ and we must mape $x_2 \to x_3\ne x_2, x_1$.  This is basically the Infinity hotel-- make we for the extra point by shoving everyone else one point further.  But can we do that in thi interval $(0,1)$? Does there exist an infinite sequence $x_1,x_2, x_3, .....$?

Well, obvious there is.  We can do $\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 14....$ or $\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 18, ... $ or any we want.  So $g:[0,1)\to (0,1)$ can be $g(x) = x$ if $x \not \in \{\frac 1n\}$ and $g(0) = \frac 12$ and $g(\frac 1n) = \frac 1{n+1}$ is a bijection.

(Okay, we'll have to *prove* this is a bijection but it obviously is.  $g:\{\frac 1n; n\ge 2\}\cup\{0\} \to \{\frac 1n; n\ge 2\}$ via $g(\frac 1n)=\frac 1{n+1}$ and $g(0)=\frac 12$ is clearly bijective and $g:(0,1)\setminus \{\frac 1n\}\to (0,1)\setminus \{\frac 1n\}$ via identity is clearly bijective so...)

Now we just need the bijection $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb R$.  Well, there is $\arcsin(-\pi 2, \pi 2)\to \mathbb R$ is a bijection and $(0,1) \to (-\pi 2, \pi 2)$ via $x\mapsto \pi(x-\frac 12)$ is a bijection so ... putting it all together:

$h:[0,1)\to \mathbb R$, $h(0) = 0$, $h(\frac 1n; n\ge 2)= \arcsin (\pi*(\frac 1{n+1}-\frac 1n))$ and for all other $x$, $h(x) = \arcsin(\pi (x -\frac 12))$ will be an acceptable bijection.