# To show equal cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To show two sets have equal cardinality is it always necessary to show bijection between the sets?

suppose I have two sets A and B isn't it enough to show that there exist one onto mapping from A to B and some another onto mapping form B to A. The reason why I am asking this question is that it sometimes becomes very difficult to construct such a function which gives bijection.

For example, when I wanted to show bijection between rationals and naturals.
It was difficult to construct such a function and later found out that
$f(m,n)=2^{m-1}(2n-1)$

will do the work.

Now,recently I came across another problem that show that [0,1] and (0,1) have equal cardinality.
I was able to construct onto mapping from (0,1) to [0,1] and also another onto mapping from [0,1] to (0,1) but still now I couldn't construct such a function which will biject the two sets.

Comment: Yes, the two onto maps would imply existence of a bijection. Of course it doesn't immediately give a way to construct the bijection.

Comment: so, what should our aproach be to solve such problems. for example take the problem that I have given how should I aproach it?

Comment: @coffeemath that isn't very obvious. In fact it requires AC.

Comment: @Umberto I once saw a proof [assuming given two *injections*] using a kind of recursive definition of points in the sets $A,B$ which have or do not have ancestors in either $A$ or $B.$ But I don't know if the recursive construction of this map involves AC (not being expert on that topic).

Comment: @coffeemath: Using two injections to construct a bijection is the essence of the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, and the axiom of choice is not needed to prove it. You are right, however, about the surjections version using the axiom of choice in an essential way.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't necessary to construct an explicit bijection if you have a result at hand you can apply. For instance, the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem states that if there are injections $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to A$, then there exists a bijection $h : A \to B$.

In your last example, it isn't hard to find injections $f : [0,1] \to (0,1)$ and $g : (0,1) \to [0,1]$, so there must exist a bijection between the sets, although we didn't demonstrate a specific example of one.

Comment: Under AC a pair of onto functions works as well, which is what OP asked about.  Given $f:  A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ both onto, you can construct $h: B \to A$ injective by relating each element of $B$ to one of the elements of $A$ that $f$ maps to it, and similarly $h': A \to B$ injective from $g$, and apply Schroeder-Bernstein.

Comment: Is their any  easy way to construct bijective making ?

Comment: @ShubhamUgare in general, no. In the specific case of $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ it isn't hard to write one down. I didn't look but almost certainly this has been asked and answered on MSE already, so you might try searching.

Comment: Here is one example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1 you can check the right side-bar for links to similar questions.

Comment: @Umberto That example 160738 was a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1].$ Of course it wouldn't be hard to adapt it.

Answer (score 2):

To biject $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$ let $A$ be the set of numbers $\frac12 \pm \frac{1}{2n}$ for $n=1,2,...$ Then for each $x$ in A map it to the next (in the sense of closer to $1/2$) element of $A,$ and on the complement map $x$ to itself. For the inverse map from $(0,1)$ back to $[0,1]$ use the set $B=A - \{0,1\}$ and this time map the elements of $B$ "away" from $1/2$ to the next element, except that e.g $1/4$ would map back to $0,$ since in the forward map $0=1/2-1/(2*1)$ went to the right to the point $1/2-1/(2*2)=1/4.$ Similarly $3/4$ maps to $1.$ under the inverse map.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this bijection. Since $A$ and $B$ are countable I don't see how mapping their elements is helping us map between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh I get it. The answers for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1?lq=1 helped a lot. +1

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yes, the whole intervals are in each case uncountable, however the bijection is taken to be the identity map on the (uncountable) complement of the set $A$ so no problem comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To show that two sets have the same cardinality you have to *prove* there *exists* a bijection between the two sets.

One way is to find an explicit, preferably human readable, formula that defines such bijection.

Another way is to break the equicardinality into steps, and in each intermediate finding a simple bijection between the relevant sets; then use the fact that the composition of bijections is a bijection (for example when you prove that $\Bbb{|R|=|R^N|}$ by passing through $2^\Bbb N$ and $2^{\Bbb{N\times N}}$).

Another way is to use the Cantor-Bernstein theorem which tells you that if there are injections $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$, then there is a bijection $h\colon A\to B$. This is very useful since more often than not it is easier to come up with injections, than with bijections. (You can use the version that replaces injections by surjections, but in the general case there is an essential use of the axiom of choice here; that being said, in some cases surjections do suffice, e.g. when one of the sets involved is countable.)

Finally, you can use cardinal arithmetic. Cardinal arithmetic is the abstraction of all the previous methods, and it often assumes that you're sufficiently familiar with them to write the details if necessary. For example, $\Bbb {|N|\leq|Z|\leq|N\times N|\leq|N|}$ to establish that $\Bbb Z$ is countable, this implicitly assumes that you're able to generate injections witnessing each $\leq$, and with Cantor-Bernstein's theorem that gives us the wanted equality.

Answer (score -1):

Existence of onto map from $A$ to $B$ gives card$(A)\leq$ card$(B)$ and existence of onto map from $B$ to $A$ gives card$(B)\leq$ card$(A)$ . In either way we can say that card$(A)=$ card$(B)$  i.e. there must be a bijection between $A$ and $B.$
But generally we have to show that two sets are of equal cardinality or not, we are not intersting in bijective map and thats  not so simple to find such a bijection.

Comment: "Existence of onto map from $A$ to $B$ gives $card(A) \le card(B)$" is false even for finite sets. Even if you switch the inequality, the result you suggest requires non-trivial set theory.