# What are injective functions that map [0, infinity) to [0, 1) and [0, 1) to [0, infinity)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For [0, 1) to [0, infinity) I have that [this piecewise function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrByX.png) that I believe is injective. For [0, infinity) to [0, 1), I consulted [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769088/is-there-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-infinity), but the set bounds are different.

Comment: $\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x)$ is a nice function from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,1)$.  And, $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ is the inverse.

Comment: There are infinitely many of them! If you want us to list them all, we could go on for ever.

Comment: Not all! Unless you're so inclined :)

Comment: By example $f(x)=x$ is injective in $[0,1)$. The same for $f(x)=x^2$, etc... and their images are contained in $[0,\infty)$.