# How can I define a bijection between sets $[-2,1)$ and $(3,5)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to define a bijection between sets $[-2,1)$ and $(3,5)$. How can I do that?

Comment: Does "particular" have a meaning?

Comment: Use the bijection defined [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1) and combine with a linear map.

Comment: First map $[-2,1)$ to $[3,5)$ by a linear function, and then select countably many elements in $(3,5)$ and stuff the $3$ in between them using the Hilbert's Hotel trick.

Comment: The essential idea is in the accepted answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1); it requires just a little modification to deal with your intervals.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott should I make an answer with that?

Comment: @RSerrao: Up to you; I’d be inclined to leave a bit of work for the OP. Perhaps write out a bijection between $[3,5)$ and $(3,5)$ and then suggest composing it with a linear map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will write here how you should take $[3, 5) $ into $(3,5) $ and then you can compose @JeanMarie's map with mine to get the desired bijection.

Let us define the set $X = \{x_i = 3 + \frac1 {2^i} | i \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{3\} $ (let $x_0 = 3$) we know that $X $ has a countable infinite number of elements.

Let us define $\phi(x): [3, 5) \to (3,5) $ as follows:

$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}\phi(x) = x, x \not\in X\\ \phi(x) = x_{i+1}, x \in X, x = x_i
\end{cases} $$

$\phi $ is a bijection thus a composition with an appropriate linear map gives what you want.

Comment: @user391135 it is

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that maps open set $(-2,1)$ onto open set $(3,5)$ which is a different issue. When I realized that I was on a different problem, I wanted to erase this "answer". But the adequate answer by @RSerrao uses mine as a step. Therefore, I leave it...

On the graphics below, have a look at the red intervals: one is $(-2,1)$ on $x$ axis, the other is $(3,5)$ on $y$ axis. The correspondence between them is an affine equation ($y=ax+b$), precisely:

$$\tag{1}y=(2/3)x+(13/3).$$

It can be explained by a kind of "mirror reflecting": the ray (vector $GH$) coming from $x \in  (-2,1)$  is "reflected" into the straight line $HI$ with impact in a certain  $y \in (3,5)$ that can be computed with formula $(1).$

[image]

Comment: Your function takes -2 to 3, but 3 is not in the image set

Comment: @user391135 you can check my answer

Comment: I understand now that I have worked with closed sets : I didn't pay enough attention to the question.

Comment: A lot of work went into this and it is still a helpful thing. +1