# Prove that the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,\infty)$ have the same cardinality

Tags: cardinals

I have to proof that the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(0,\infty)$ have the same cardinality. I find some similar example with $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ but I still have no idea to solve it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1

Comment: Another bijection: $-\log x$.

Answer (score 24):

$x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(1, + \infty)$. Then use a translation to get $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: As a bonus, that even works for rational numbers.

Comment: there are plenty of functions that share that property, too. e.g. : $x \mapsto - ln(x)$ bijects from $(0, 1)$ to $(+\infty, 0)$

Comment: Thanks, I  just finish this question.

Answer (score 8):

Define $f : (0, 1) \to (0, \infty)$ by $$f(x) = -\frac{x^2}{x-1}.$$ We can use methods from calculus to verify that this is a bijection. Since $f$ is a bijection between $(0, 1)$ and $(0, \infty)$, these two sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Now that I think about it, $g(x) = -\frac{x}{x-1}$ is simpler and works equally well.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do it:

The function

$y = \tanh(x) \tag{1}$

maps $(0, \infty) \to (0, 1)$.  Furthermore,

$y'(x) = \cosh^{-2}(x) > 0 \tag{2}$

for $x \in (0, \infty)$.  Thus $\tanh(x)$ is a bijection, as is $\tanh^{-1}(x)$ which maps $(0, 1) \to (0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Another explicit bijection: $x \mapsto \tan{(\pi x/2)}$ is continuous, increasing on $(0,1)$, tends to $0$ as $x \to 0$, and $\infty$ as $x \to 1$, so it is a bijection $(0,1) \to (0,\infty)$

Comment: There are uncountably many bijections, we don't need to list them all...!

Comment: Since there are uncountably many, we can't! At least there are only countably many continuous ones... But it's worth having a few examples to hand for various circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

A bijection is a function that, for each distinct input has a unique and distinct output, and for each distinct output has a unique and distinct input.

To prove that 2 sets have the same cardinality, you can simple prove that there is a bijective transformation from one to the other.

For $(0, 1)$ to $(0, +\infty)$, there are an infinite number bijective functions.

For example:

$$x \mapsto -ln(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

What about $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}arctan(x)$ is a bijection between $(0, \infty)$ and $(0, 1)$. So they have the same cardinality since we can construct a bijection between the two intervals.