# Finding a function from one interval to another

Tags: functions

Is there a one-to-one function from $(-∞,0]$ onto $(0,1/2)$?

So I was thinking of a function of the form $$\frac{1}{x+n}+m$$
I'm used to problems in which you have to map an interval into another (where infinity is not involved), which might be solved with a system of linear equalities.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, such function exists. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, both are of the same cardinality. Do you mean something like "continuous function"?

Comment: My problem here is with the interval $(-∞,0]$ because I've always worked with 'finite' intervals... I think that the function might be something like $$\frac{1}{x+n}+m$$

Comment: Yes MigMit, that would be in the best case

Comment: It cannot be... It is not defined for $-n$

Comment: There is no continuous one-to-one function like that. There exist both continuous injection and surjection, but no continuous bijection.

Comment: @Dr.Valdi: Welcome to Math.SE! You should add your [thoughts and specific issues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899363/finding-a-function-from-one-interval-to-another#comment5988669_2899363) to the question (by editing), rather than leaving them in the comments. Your questions are likely to be better received when you do.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1. Then it remains to find a bijection between  $(−\infty,0]$ and $(0,1]$ and another one between $(0,1/2)$ and $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suggested in comments something of the form $\frac{1}{x+n}+m$

- If you used $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-2}+\frac12$ then you would have $f:(-\infty,0] \to [0,\frac12)$ which is a bijection but not exactly onto $(0,\frac12)$
- If you used $g(x) = \frac{1}{x-3}+\frac12$ then you would have $g:(-\infty,0] \to [\frac16,\frac12) \subset (0,\frac12)$ which is a one-to-one injection but not a bijection
- If you combine these and used $h(x) = \frac{1}{x-2}+\frac12$ when $x$ is not an integer and $h(x)= \frac{1}{x-3}+\frac12$ when $x$ is an integer then you would have $h:(-\infty,0] \to (0,\frac12)$ which is a  bijection but not a continuous function

You cannot have a continuous bijection because of the problem that it must put $0$ inside the open interval $(0,\frac12)$

Answer (score 4):

There exist one-to-one functions from $(-\infty,0]$ onto $(0,\frac12)$. For a proof, consider first $f(x)=\frac1{2(1-x)}$. That maps $(-\infty,0)$ onto $(0,\frac12)$. We now need to change $f$ so $0$ can get mapped somewhere. The standard method is Hilbert's hotel: We let $g$ be function given by $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, $g(0)=f(-1)$, $g(-1)=f(-2)$ and so on.

However, no *continuous* one-to-one function from $(-\infty,0]$ onto $(0,\frac12)$ exists. A continuous one-to-one function is either strictly monotone increasing or strictly monotone decreasing. It follows that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ must be $0$ or $\frac12$. As $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=\frac12$, so the function does not map into $(0,\frac12)$.