# Prove: for every $a < b \in \mathbb{R}, \ |(a, b)| = |[a,b)| = |(a.b]| = |[a,b]| = |\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove: the cardinality of every interval in $ \mathbb{R}$ is equals to $ \vert \mathbb{R} \vert = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$

I know how to prove that the cardinality of every closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ equals to $ 2^{\aleph_{0}}$, but  I'm not sure how exactly the proof differs for an open interval / half open interval.

the proof of a closed interval would be:

first, I'd like to prove that: $[a, b] = [-1, 1]$. 
we'll define the function $f: [-1 , 1] \to [a, b]$ by $f(t) = a+ (t+1) \cdot \frac {b-a}{2} $

i'll prove that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

**one-to-one**

let $t_1, t_2 \in [-1,1]$

$$  f(t_1) = f(t_2)$$
$$ \iff$$
$$ a+(t_1 + 1) \cdot \frac {b-a}{2} = a+(t_2 + 1) \cdot \frac {b-a}{2}\\\ \Longrightarrow t_1 = t_2 $$

onto - of the definition of $f$.
because $f$ is a bijection that'd enough to prove that $\vert [-1,1]\vert \geq \vert \mathbb{R} \vert $.

Let $g: (-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$. 
$$g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2x-1}\ \ \text{if}\ & \frac{1}{2}<x\leq1\\
\frac{1}{2x+1}\ \ \text{if}\ & -1\leq x<\frac{-1}{2}\\
2x\ \ \text{if}\ & \frac{-1}{2}\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}
\end{array}\right.$$

I'll prove that $g$ is onto.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

if $x <1$ then $\frac{1}{2} < \frac {1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac {1}{x} +1 \right) < 1 \ \text{and} \ f \left( \frac {1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac {1}{x} +1 \right)\right) = \frac {1}{2\cdot \left(\frac {1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac {1}{x} +1\right)\right)-1} 
 = x$

in the same way, if $x < -1 $ so  $ \frac{-1}{2} < \frac {1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac {1}{x} +1 \right) >  -1$

hence $f \left( \frac {1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac {1}{x} +1 \right)\right) = x$, otherwise, $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, therefore $f \left( \frac {x}{2} \right) = x$.

Comment: Please note that if you add or subtrack to an uncountable set countable many elements , the cardinality does not change...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would only prove it for the open interval $(a,b),$ (using e.g. a modification of $f:\mathbb{R}\to (-\pi/2,\pi/2), \; x\mapsto \arctan x$) and then you have
$$|\mathbb{R}| = \vert (a,b) \vert \leq \vert (a,b] \vert \leq \vert \mathbb{R} \vert \quad \Rightarrow  \quad  \vert (a,b] \vert = \vert \mathbb{R} \vert, $$
where the inequalities follow since $(a,b) \subset (a,b] \subset \mathbb{R},$ and similarily for other half-open and the closed interval.

Answer (score 0):

Or, have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160741/403337).  Thus, $(a,b)$ and $[a,b)$ are in one-one correspondence...  and use $\arctan $ for equivalence with $\mathbb R$.