# Is there an injective function defined in $\mathbb{R}$ with $[0,1]$ as its image?

Tags: functions

I know that there are injective functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$ that take all the values in $(0,1)$ for one $x$ (that is, with image $(0,1)$). For example this one:

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}, \ \ x\in\mathbb{R}$$

But I can't think of an injective function defined in $\mathbb{R}$ that has $[0,1]$ as its image. Does such a function exist and if not, why?

Comment: It won't be continuous, but such functions do exist. I think on this site you can find examples of bijections from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$, so you would just need to compose your function with such an example. See [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160741/43239) to construct such a bijection.

Comment: Sure, just compose your $f$ with any bijection from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$. There's a standard trick to find one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this function will work

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan x}{\pi}$ if $x\notin\mathbb N$

$f(1)=0$, $f(2)=1$ and $f(n+2)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan n}{\pi}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

Comment: I think that with this function you don't get 1/2 + arctan(1)/pi in the image of f. Neither 1/2+arctan(2)/pi.

Comment: @michailvazaios $f(3)=f(1+2)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan 1}{\pi}$. $f(4)=f(2+2)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan 2}{\pi}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider any bijective function $g:\Bbb R\to (0,1)$. For example $g(x)=e^{-e^{-x}}$.

Map every irrational $u$ to $g(u)$.

Let $\{a_n\}$ a sequence of all rationals and $\{b_n\}$ a sequence of all rationals of $[0,1]$. Map $a_n$ to $g(b_n)$.

Comment: So how do I get an A such that f(A)=0 and a B such that f(B)=1?

Comment: The sequence $\{b_n\}$ contains $0$ and $1$. Say $b_j=0$ and $b_k=1$. Then $f(a_j)=0$ and $f(a_k)=1$.

Comment: But this means that $a_j$ is mapped to $g(b_j)$ and not $b_j$. We don't know for sure if $g(b_j)$=0. If I don't understand something in your solution please explain