# Is this a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
n  & \text{if $n$ is irrational} \\
(n+1)/2, & \text{if $n$ is rational}
\end{cases}$$

The way the function is constructed we can get to every rational in $(0,1)$ and every $f(n)$ is in $(0,1)$. Also $0$ maps to $1/2$ and $f(n)$ maps to $0$ if and only $f(n) = -1$, which we don't need to consider since $n$ must be in $(0,1)$. The function is clearly injective.

Comment: What is the value of $x$ that gives $f(x)=\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Ok understood. This is confusing because the book I am using asks these questions in chapter $1$ and every construction I see for the solutions to these problems is rather complicated.

Comment: Related: [How to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1?rq=1)

Comment: Exactly the same argument in that link except let $x_{0} = 0$. I just thought there would be a simpler construction since I didn't see anything in this book (Abbott) that would make me consider such an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is surjective if $y \in (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \exists x \in [0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q} \ y=f(x) = \frac{x+1}{2}$.

But $y< \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow x <0$, so it isn't surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Rational numbers $< \frac{1}{2}$ in the second set doesn't map to any element in the first set, so there do not exist an inverse function. Therefore, it is not a bijection.

On the other hand, I think the function from $[0,1) \cup \mathbb{Q(-1,0)} $ to $(0,1)$ is a bijection.