# Bijection from set x := [0,1) to the set of positive real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I thought I could use $x = \tan(\pi x/2)$, but this only works for $x: = (0,1)$. How should I address the 0? I saw somewhere else's to find a function for $x = 1/n$ (eg ($f(x) = 1/(n+1)$), but I did not understand this.

Comment: Hi there, I suppose you mean $f(x)=\tan(\pi x/2)$, if so, notice that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @CristianBaeza $0$ isn't positive.

Comment: A common idea is to pick out a tiny (countable) subset of the domain and codomain and "let them deal with the troublesome endpoint", while making the rest of the function something simple. The many answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1) illustrate that idea in several ways.

Comment: Those were different days.  A question like that wouldn't attract about 500 likes today.  Aram2 and I will be lucky to get 3 likes total.  But I do notice that none of their answers are the same as mine.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1

Comment: ups!! my bad...

Answer (score 4):

Write the positive numbers and $[0,1)$ as
$$(0,\infty) = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (n,n+1], \quad [0,1)  = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty [1-\tfrac1{n+1},1-\tfrac1{n+2}) .$$
Let $f$ restricted to $(n,n+1]$ be the linear function that takes $n$ to $1-\frac1{n+2}$, and $n+1$ to $1-\frac1{n+1}$.