# Is it true that there is a bijection $[0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, real-numbers

Is there is a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

I thought of an instance, $$\frac{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{x-1}.$$

Comment: Of course there is.  They are both sets of size continuum.  What makes you think there is not?  -1 and vote to close.

Comment: @RossMillikan Maybe the OP isn't familiar with cardinality ...

Comment: No bijection can be continuous because one has a closed end (0) and the other does not.  One point can't spoil anything about bijections with infinite sets because you can always sweep it under the rug.

Comment: $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ is not a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$.  Do you know a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: If you do know one, then cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1)

Comment: You don't need to know *what* a bijection might be to know a bijection must exist.  We know a bijection must exist because they have the same cardinality.  Is there any reason you *care* what it is?  $x\mapsto \frac {x\sqrt{1-x}}{x-1}$ is *not* it. (It doesn't map to any negative numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:[0,1)=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_{n\ge 1}[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)\to\mathbb R$ by $f(0)=0$, if $x\in [\frac1{2k+1},\frac1{2k})$, $f(x)=-2k(2k+1)x+3k$, and if $x\in [\frac1{2k+2},\frac1{2k+1})$, $f(x)=(2k+1)(2k+2)x-3k-2$.

A simpler example: $g:[0,1)\to\mathbb R$, if $x\in[0,\frac13]$ then $g(x)=6x-1$, if $x\in (\frac13,\frac23)$ then $g(x)=\frac{1}{2-3x}$, and if $x\in(\frac23,1)$ then $g(x)=\frac{1}{3x-3}$.

Comment: Does n have  to be equal to 0?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. $\bigcup_{n\ge 0}$ is just a symbol for the union of sets

Comment: But as a denominator in $1/n$, n might not be 0.

Comment: Oh yes, I will fix that

Answer (score 0):

$(0,1) \subset [0,1) \subset \mathbb R$ so $|(0, 1)| \le |[0,1)| \le |\mathbb R|$.

And $f: (0,1)\to (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ via $x \mapsto \pi x-\frac \pi 2$ is a bijection so $|(0,1)| = |(0,\pi)|$.

And $\tan:  (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2) = \mathbb R$ is a bijection.

So $|\mathbb R|= | (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)| = |(0,1)| \le |[0,1)| \le |\mathbb R|$.

So $|[0,1)| = |\mathbb R|$.

So, yes, a bijection between $[0,1)\to \mathbb R$ exist.

But is there any reason we need to actually *find* one?  Isn't enough to to just know there *is* one?

We can map $(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ by considering $x \mapsto \tan (\pi\cdot x-\frac \pi 2)$.  but we haven't got $0$ maping to anything.

We can kludge $[0,1) \to (0,1)$ by mapping $0\mapsto \frac 12$ then $\frac 12 \mapsto \frac 14$ and $\frac 1{2^k} \mapsto \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$ and $x \mapsto x$ if $x \ne \frac 1{2^m}$ for any natural $m$.  That is a bijection.

So if we compose the two $[0,1) \to (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ via for every $\frac 1{2^k} \mapsto \tan(\frac 1{2^{k+1}}\pi)$ and for every other $x \mapsto \tan(\pi\cdot x)$.

That's a valid bijection.  But there are many others.

It's worth noting a *continuous* bijection, $f$, can't exist.  We need to map $0$ somewhere.  But then the values immediately to the left and right of $f(x)$ will be "ripped" apart.

Comment: $\tan$ is not defined at $\pi/2$. Also, why do you need $1/2^k\mapsto 1/2^{k+1}$? Wouldn't $1/k\mapsto 1/(k+1)$ suffice?

Comment: Isn't $\tan \frac \pi 2$ .... Argh.... brain fart.  Use $(0,1)$ to $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ instead.  As for $\frac 1{2^k} \to \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$ vs. $\frac 1k\to \frac 1{k+1}$.  Six of one, half a dozen of the other.  Whichever is more intuitive.  Which for me is $\frac 1{2^k} \to \frac 1{2^{k+1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use usual protocol:

1. Prove "one to one" (if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$).
2. Now we need to show $f$ is onto $\Bbb R$ (This means that $\Bbb R=\text{Range}(f)$).

Now the range of $f$ is the set of values that $f$ maps to from the domain. Now, we need to show that

$$\Bbb R\subset \text{Range}(f)\subset\Bbb R$$

for clear perspective use DESMOS graph calculator you can clearly observe in the graph that given function is not onto.