# $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ invertible and surjective (onto)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Is there any (not necessarily continuous) function $f:[0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f$ is invertible, $f(x)$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=1$ with $f(x)$ approaching $+\infty$ as $x$ moves closer to $1$, and that $\mathrm{dom}(f^{-1})=\mathbb{R}$? I've the feeling that such a function can't actually exist. Any idea?

Comment: Hint: both spaces can be broken into infinitely many half-open intervals. For example,$$[0,1)=\left[0,\frac12\right)\cup\left[\frac12,\frac23\right)\cup\left[\frac23\cup\frac34\right)\cup\cdot$$and$$\Bbb R=[0,\infty)\cup[-1,0)\cup[-2,-1)\cup[-3,-2)\cup\cdots.$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1)

Comment: Sorry I forgot one of the constraints... :(

Comment: It is possible even with the extra constraint.

Comment: Indeed, e.g. by choosing some well-known functions with asymptotes (like in my answer) and there are many of those

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger yes, your example works even with the restriction. Thank you!

Comment: See my comments under my answer for more. (If the two sets have different Euler characteristics - defined as "vertices minus edges" - then the graph must use infinitely many pieces.)

Comment: In two dimensions, the equivalent notion is "vertices minus edges plus faces", which you may have heard of before. (I won't define "tame" here, but full theorem is, two tame sets have a tame bijection iff their Euler characteristics are the same and their highest dimensions are the same.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example. Note that the graph has infinitely many pieces; in fact, this is necessary for this problem.[image]

Comment: Interesting. Why are infinitely many pieces necessary? Similarly to how one can extend $(0,1)$ to $[0,1)$?

Comment: If a graph has finitely many pieces, then you may compute its _Euler characteristic_ as follows: an open curve (without endpoints) has value $-1$; a closed curve (with both endpoints) or an isolated point has value $1$; a half-open curve has value $0$. Add these up to get the graph's Euler characteristic. It turns out that this always equals the Euler characteristic of both the domain and the codomain. Since $[0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ have different Euler characteristics ($0$ and $-1$), the graph of a bijection must use infinitely many pieces.

Comment: Another way to think of the same calculation: it's _vertices minus edges_ (where vertices are isolated points or endpoints, and edges are intervals). A closed interval has two vertices and one edge so it has Euler characteristic $-1$. My graph has Euler characteristic $\infty-\infty$, which is undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is actually extremely useful and interesting. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the Euler characteristic should be 0 of your graph? Because each piece has euler char 0?

Comment: @LegNaiB This only applies to so-called "tame sets", which have finitely many pieces. (The "vertices minus edges" definition is probably clearer here.)

Comment: ah thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

We know that $[0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ have the same size (both are uncountably infinite), so there actually exists a bijection between those two sets.

For matching $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ you can simply take an asymptotic function and change it so that it fits into the interval, e.g. $\frac{1}{1-x} - 1$.

To get all $\mathbb{R}$ as the image, you can just define the function stepwise by going to infinity on $[0.5, 1)$ and to negative infinity on $(0, 0.5)$. As the function doesn't need to be continuous, you can just add some extra value for $x=0$:

$$
x \in [0.5, 1): f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} - 2, \\
x\in (0,0.5): f(x) = -\frac{1}{x} + 2, \\
x = 0: f(x)= 0
$$

Comment: But then $f(0)=f(0.5)=0$ right? So it's not invertible

Comment: This is not bijective (invertible) because $f(x)=f(.5)$.

Comment: Oh right, then add the example of the link with the bijection between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$